# Fast utility that indexes files/directories on centos 6 for faster searching through the filesystem

Tags: grep, search

I need to often search a large directory structure (with 1 G / 13K files of data). find / grep take a lot of time. Is there any utility (or can one make an index of these files) for faster searching.

Comment: What about locate?

Comment: Isn't this just a software recommendation request?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your Unix/Linux Flavor you can easily use `slocate`/`mlocate`/all the derivates.

Usually u can just hit `updatedb` as root and then do

```
locate <searchpattern>
```

Hitting `updatedb` again will update your present db and reflects the changes on the fs.

Answer (score 1):

In a similar situation (differential backup) I do this first:

```
find /directory/ -printf . &>/dev/null
```

This way I get all the file metadata into the cache with optimal hard disk performance (would probably not make much sense with an SSD).